# tomcat JNDI database configuration

Tags: database, tomcat, jdbc, jndi

I have the following in C:/Tomcat6/conf/context.xml:

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/MyDatasource" name="jdbc/MyDatasource" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>


</Context>
```

and the following in C:/Tomcat6/conf/server.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDatasource"
    auth="Container"
    driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    maxactive="100"
    maxidle="30"
    maxwait="10000"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"    
    jdbcUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/SAFEHOUSE-UK;integratedSecurity=true;">
```

I have jtds-1.2.5.jar in C:/Tomcat6/lib.

Yet when I hit my application I get the following:

> org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC
>   driver of class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL
>   'null'    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
>     at
>   com.safehouse.safeservices.authenticate.AdminLoginForm.getpassword(Unknown
>   Source)

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Post the complete stack trace. There must be more to it than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1、modify the connection url

```
 jdbcUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1305;DatabaseName=your databasename"
```

Answer (score 1):

From Apache Tomcat 6 documentation: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html
maybe the mistake was in attribute name, try to use **url** instead of **jdbcUrl**